# Best method to update array of json using mongo queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is the data that I have in my one of my database collections.

```
{
    "name" : "data1",
    "email" : "sample@example.com",
    "amount": ''
},
{
    "name":"data2"
    "email":"sample2@ex.com",
    "amount":''
}
```

I need to write a post request to update the fields.

I am getting an array of JSON field consisting of the data in the following format.

```
{
    "changes": [
        {
            "email":"sample@example.com",
            "amount":2300
        },
        {
            "email":"sample2@ex.com",
            "amount":1900

        }
    ]
}
```

I need to search the email and update the data with corresponding amount.

for example, in this case, the data after post request will be:-

```
{
    "name" : "data1",
    "email" : "sample@example.com",
    "amount": 2300
},
{
    "name":"data2"
    "email":"sample2@ex.com",
    "amount":1900
}
```

```
var user = require('./models/user.js')

exports.updateAmount = function(req, res) {
    if(req && req.body.changes)
    {
           // I am facing problem on how to write this step
          // Participant.updateMany  //this step 

            .exec(function(err, data) {
                if(err)
                {
                    res.status(400).send({
                        success: false,
                        error: err
                    })
                }
                else
                {
                    res.status(200).send({
                        success: false,
                        message: 'success',
                        body: data
                    })
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this is because the changes object is assigned to a variable called changes.

You have to remove the JSON object from the changes variable by parsing the changes variable to JSON like this:

```
const change = JSON.parse(changes)

const new_changes = change.changes
```

Basically make the request body JSON, then access the "changes" parent name with the `dot notation`
now use the variable `"new_changes"` and your updated code  will work.